# How to get summary of connections for LinkedIn API using omniauth-linkedin gem

Tags: linkedin-api

I was trying to get summary of connections using omniauth-linkedin gem

here is the configuration details on the same

### Code

```
:scope => 'r_fullprofile r_basicprofile r_emailaddress r_network', 
:fields => ["id", "summary","positions", "location:(name)", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "industry", "connections:(headline,first-name,last-name,summary,interests,skills,educations)"]
```

But Linkedin API returning only headline, `firstname` and `lastname` .

Is there anyway I can get details ?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation for the Connections API.
 As is stated [in the documentation](https://developers.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api):

> "For 1st degree connections, you may only retrieve profile fields available with the r_basicprofile member permission"

interests, skills and educations are not available with the r_basicprofile permissions.

The summary field is available with the r_basicprofile permission, but the documentation notes

> "Not available via connections API."

This is why you are unable to get these fields when you make the call you provided.