# Sparkle LinkedIn API: summary and skills fields always empty

Tags: c#, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the summary and Skills fields from the LinkedIn API using Sparkle.LinkedIn.
Everything works fine, **I can read Headline, FirstName and LastName** fields, but **Skills**, **Summary**, Industry, **DateOfBirth** and other fields are **always empty** even if the LinkedIn profile **has them for sure**.

Here is the code I'm using when the user has already been authenticated and I have the token:

```
var fields = FieldSelector.For<Person>()
    .WithId()
    .WithFirstName()
    .WithLastName()
    .WithEmailAddress()
    .WithHeadline()
    .WithPictureUrl()
    .WithPublicProfileUrl()
    .WithSummary()
    .WithIndustry()
    .WithDateOfBirth()
    .WithSkills();

var config = new LinkedInApiConfiguration("api-key", "key-secret");    
var api = new LinkedInApi(config);    
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(error_description))
{
    Response.Write(error + "<br/>" + error_description);
}
else
{
    var redirectUrl = "my-redirect-url";
    var userToken = api.OAuth2.GetAccessToken(code, redirectUrl);    
    var acceptLanguages = new string[] { "it-IT","en-US", };

    var user = new UserAuthorization(userToken.AccessToken);
    Person profile = api.Profiles.GetMyProfile(user,acceptLanguages,fields);
    Response.Write(profile.Headline + "<br/>");
    Response.Write(profile.Summary + "<br/>"); //always empty
    Response.Write(profile.Industry + "<br/>"); //always empty
    Response.Write(profile.PictureUrl + "<br/>");  //always empty
    if(profile.Skills!=null)  //always null
    {
       foreach (var sk in profile.Skills.Skill)
       {
           Response.Write(sk.SkillName.Name + "<br/>");
       }
    }
    Response.Write(profile.Lastname + "<br/>");
    Response.Write(profile.DateOfBirth.Year + "<br/>"); //always empty

}
```

**How can I retrieve also the summary and skills fields?**

Comment: The code looks good. It appears to be a nuance of LinkedIn, perhaps authorization as Achille suggests.

Comment: Searching in Internet seems there is a big undocumented change in the Linked API, as they are closing the access to most of the fields for the open API. Only big companies partners of LinkedIn can access it. This is what I've read, if someone could confirm it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't comment your post, but what I can tell is that this of course isn't a logic order error. Looking at it really quickly, one thing I would try is to replace everything in the field selector with `.WithAllFields()`.

Also one thing I found here [How to get summary of connections for LinkedIn API using omniauth-linkedin gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752480/how-to-get-summary-of-connections-for-linkedin-api-using-omniauth-linkedin-gem), is that you might need more permission than what you have now (I've never used this api, so im not sure)

Comment: Thanks Achille, alteady tried with .WithAllFields() but same identical results

Comment: Hi, today I will try to replicate your code on my machine so I can do more debuggin, could you share other parts of the code (be careful not to show any sensitive data) so the code I'll be testing can be a similiar to yours as possible?  Also, did you import the library from nuget?

Comment: Yes, I've imported from nuget, on a webform website, very easy and quickly. BTW I've found a statement on LinkedIn official site where they confirm they are not sharing data anymore to anyone and they have to review app by app to allow reading permission! Even if it's the user that gives permission to the app to read his/her data... mah. Later I'll update my post

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry to hear that, it's always awful when APIs get restricted ):